# One to many relation, pass empty model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I would like to assign users to certain company (equals Customer below). For this matter I have created a models as follows:

ApplicationUser.cs:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
  {
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
  }
```

Customer.cs:

```
  public class Customer
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

  }
```

Then in ApplicationDBContext added following:

```
  builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
  .HasOne<Customer>(s => s.Customer)
  .WithMany(u => u.ApplicationUsers)
  .HasForeignKey(u => u.CustomerId)
  .IsRequired(false)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Now when I am trying to create a new user I need to have Customer defined

```
  Customer customer = this.Context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == model.Customer.Id);
  ApplicationUser newUser = new ApplicationUser
  {
    UserName = model.Email,
    Customer = customer,
    CustomerId = customer.Id,
  };
```

otherwise I am getting an error. In above example code my Customer is null. How I can input a user without Customer? I mean if it is just a general user like admin, moderator etc.?

Here is what I get from Json:

> {type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",…} errors:
> {Customer.Country: ["The Country field is required."],…} status: 400
> title: "One or more validation errors occurred." traceId:
> "00-98502b075467df5eb3a914a864a96195-c64fbefaa40f2e0f-00" type:
> "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"

I have set this field as `[Required]` for validation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An optional Foreign Key with a value type property must be nullable.  eg

```
public Guid? CustomerId { get; set; }
```

Comment: After further investigations and removing `[Required]` from model, it says `Customer = customer,` is null inside `ApplicationUser newUser`. Any ideas how to overcome that issue? It is true, as I am not specifying any Customer, but how to get it working? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What issue?  Of course Customer is null.

Comment: I mean is there any way to save record without Customer specified in One to many relation? I have tried your solution, but as `Customer = customer` is null, changing `CustomerId` to nullable did not help.